# mysql change the order of default options

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I am testing a prebuild project where different versions of my.cnf file gets copied to /etc/

as far as i can tell /etc/my.cnf is read first, then mysql reads /etc/mysql/my.cnf afterwards, which overwrites all the settings in /etc/my.cnf, how can I reorder it to make sure /etc/my.cnf is applied last?

i have tried to delete /etc/mysql/my.cnf but that would stop mysql to start all together.

Comment: Well you can't of course. Have you considered changing your build process?

Comment: @EJP thanks i guess i just wanted to make sure, ill look into changing the build process!